# Invalid or missing web property ID

Tags: vue.js, google-analytics

I have this VueJs SFC which implements VueAnalytic and it works.

```
Vue.use(VueAnalytics, {
  id: 'UA-xxx-4',
  router
})
```

Then I need to add one more ID and the code modified to below:

```
Vue.use(VueAnalytics, {
  id: ['UA-xxx-4','AW-xxx'],
  router
})
```

Now, I could not detect the ID, "AW-xxx". It says "Invalid or missing web property ID"

Comment: Are you using an out dated package? Try https://github.com/MatteoGabriele/vue-gtag

Comment: @XTOTHEL, I am using `vue-analytics` package version 5.22.1

Comment: the author of that package suggests to switch to the vue-gtag package. https://www.npmjs.com/package/vue-analytics